# Creating a word shifter

Tags: c++

For an assignment, I am working on creating a word shifter in C++.  I have little to no experience with C++ so it has been very difficult.  I think I am really close but just missing some syntax that is part of C++.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
string s = phrase;
int length = s.length();
//find length of input to create a new string

string new_phrase[length];
//create a new string that will be filled by my for loop

for (int i=0; i<length; i++) 
//for loop to go through and change the letter from the original to the new and then            put into a string
{

    int letter = int(s[i]); 
    int new_phrase[i] = letter + shift;
//this is where I am coming up with an error saying that new_phrase is not initialized

    if (new_phrase[i] > 122)
//make sure that it goes back to a if shifting past z
    { 
        new_phrase[i] = new_phrase[i] - 26;
    }
}
cout << new_phrase<< endl;
```

Comment: Arrays must have a length that is a compile-time constant.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include any error messages and expected behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: Contrary to the comment, `string new_phrase[length];` does *not* define a string. It attempts (and fails, on a conforming compiler) to define an array of strings. From the looks of the rest of the code, you want something like `string new_phrase(s);`, which will create `new_phrase` as a copy of `s`.

Comment: Your code looks like it's full of compiler errors. You should work in smaller pieces and compile more often, and fix errors before adding more code. It would make fixing them much easier (especially when you are just learning).

Comment: What are the requirements?  What is the input data?  What is the expected output?  What is the actual input?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
 // must be unsigned char for overflow checking to work.
 char Shifter(unsigned char letter)
 {
       letter = letter + shift;

       if (letter > 'z')
           letter = letter - 26;
       return letter;
 }

// :
// :

 string new_phrase = phrase;   // mainly just allocating a string the same size.

 // Step throught each char in phrase, preform Shifter on the char, then
 // store the result in new_phrase.

 std::transform(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), new_phrase.begin(), Shifter);

 cout << new_phrase<< endl;
```

- UPDATE: made `letter` unsigned, so the overflow check works.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your syntax,I wrote an example for you.Besides,it is conventional
to write comment before it's relevant code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //test value;
    int shift = 3;
    string s = "hello string";

    //find length of input to create a new string
    int length = s.length();

    //create a new string.it's length is same as 's' and initialized with ' ';
    string new_phrase(length, ' ');

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) 
    {
        //no need to cast explicitly.It will be done implicitly.
        int letter = s[i]; 

        //It's assignment, not declaration
        new_phrase[i] = letter + shift;

        //'z' is equal to 126.but it's more readable
        if (new_phrase[i] > 'z')
        { 
            new_phrase[i] = new_phrase[i] - ('z' - 'a' + 1);
        }
    }
    cout << new_phrase<< endl;
}
```

Comment: You had the parameters for the std::string constructor backward.  I've fixed them.  (note, they were correct for C#/.NET)

Comment: @James Curran, Yeah,You got it.

Comment: Also, I just noticed (mine had the same problem), that the shift has to be done using `unsigned char`s (or `int`s). `new_phrase[i] > 'z` will almost never be true, as if it's over 127, it'll be negative.   That's a bigger change, so I'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try and investigate this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void ShiftRight( std::string &s, std::string::size_type n )
{
    if ( n >= 'Z' - 'A' + 1 ) return;

    for ( char &c : s )
    {
        bool lower_case = std::islower( c );

        c = std::toupper( c );

        c = ( c + n -'A' ) % ('Z' -'A' + 1 ) + 'A';

        if ( lower_case ) c = std::tolower( c );        
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" );

    std::cout << s << std::endl << std::endl;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 1; i <= 'Z' -'A' + 1; i++ )
    {
        std::str    std::string s( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" );

        ShiftRight( s, i );

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
VWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

As for your code then it of course is wrong. You have not to define an array of strings. And do not use magic numbers as for example 122.
Also you may include in my code a check that a next symbol is an alpha symbol.